# Text-Indent and Padding Not Working for Select Across Browsers

Tags: html, css, select, text-indent

I am having difficulty with this seemingly simple issue. I want to indent the text of my select input. There are two ways that I know to do this:

1. Text-indent
2. Padding Left

The issue is that each browser tends to allow one but not the other.

- Chrome: Both Work
- IE: Text Indent Does not work
- Safari: Padding-Left Does not work
- Firefox: Both Work

I am looking for a simply solution to allow text indentation across all browsers. Typically I have used  's for each selection, but I am hoping for a better solution. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I am also looking for a better solution than padding-left. It also seems padding-left never really centers the text across all browsers. In one browser it's centered, in another it's off.